# PHP DOMDocument not really modified with replaceChild

Tags: php, domdocument

The page **index.php** make an AJAX call to execute this code in **sauver_page.ajax.php**:

```
<?php 
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
 
    $retour = array();
    $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/w/test_save/cible.php';
    $htmlFile = new DOMDocument('1.0',"UTF-8");
    $htmlFile->loadHTMLFile($file);
    
    $contentEditable = $htmlFile->getElementById("editable");
    if($contentEditable) {
        $retour["contentEditableValue"] = $contentEditable->nodeValue;
            
        $fragment = $contentEditable->ownerDocument->createDocumentFragment();
        $fragment->appendXML("<P>voilà un nouveau doc ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."</P>");
          
        $clone = $contentEditable->cloneNode(); // Get element copy without children
        $clone->appendChild($fragment);
        
    
        
       
        $retour["cloneId"] = print_r($clone->getAttribute('id'), true);
        $retour["cloneValue"] = print_r($clone->nodeValue, true);
        
        $newnode = $htmlFile->importNode($clone, true);
        $htmlFile->appendChild($newnode);
       
     
        $retour["replaceSuccessRetour"] = $contentEditable->parentNode->replaceChild($newnode, $contentEditable);
        //$retour["replaceSuccessRetour"] = $contentEditable->parentNode->replaceChild($contentEditable, $newnode);
       
        if(!$retour["replaceSuccessRetour"]){
            $retour["replaceSuccess"] = "échouée";
        } else {
            $retour["replaceSuccess"] = "ok";
        }
        
        //$contentEditable = $htmlFile->getElementById("editable");
        $retour["contentEditableModif"] = $contentEditable->nodeValue;
         
        $retour["sauve"] = $htmlFile->saveHTMLFile($file);
        if(!$retour["sauve"]){
            $retour["sauvegarde"] = "échouée";
        } else {
            $retour["sauvegarde"] = "ok";
        }
    } else {
        $retour["contentEditable"] = "pas de balise 'editable'";
    }
    echo json_encode($retour);

?>
```

And i am surprised to observe that in response of the AJAX call :

```
contentEditableValue    "ouuuups"
cloneId "editable"
cloneValue  "voilà un nouveau doc 2021-10-08 09:37:46"
replaceSuccessRetour    Object { }
replaceSuccess  "ok"
contentEditableModif    "ouuuups"
sauve   220
sauvegarde  "ok"
```

`contentEditableModif`  "ouuuups" must be the new one value like `voilà un nouveau doc 2021-10-08 09:37:46`!

And the `$htmlFile->saveHTMLFile($file);` works, it contains the good new value : `voilà un nouveau doc 2021-10-08 09:37:46`

**Question :** Why `$retour["contentEditableModif"]` stay with the old value ?

===
Other interessant subject :

- [How to saveHTML of DOMDocument without HTML wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879946/how-to-savehtml-of-domdocument-without-html-wrapper)
- [DOMDOCUMENT | PHP: save getElementById output into new HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723274/domdocument-php-save-getelementbyid-output-into-new-html-file)

Comment: Just because you called `$contentEditable->parentNode->replaceChild($newnode, $contentEditable)`, does not mean what the variable `$contentEditable` contains, has also changed. That is still referring to your _old_ node.

Comment: Okay, but in this case, why `$htmlFile->saveHTMLFile($file)` save the good things ? I have tried with uncomment the line `//$contentEditable = $htmlFile->getElementById("editable");`, and it is the same result.

Comment: Because `$htmlFile` refers to your whole DOMDocument object, and in that you replaced the existing node with a different one.